# How to open tall window with pole?

Tags: windows

Just moved into the new place and am trying to figure out how to open this window. It has the pole (second picture) nearby. No amount of searching leads to the right type of window? Any ideas? Do I need a different pole?

(Edit: here's a closeup of both sides of the pole: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nA9f.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Insert one arm of the half circle into the loop and push up.

Comment: Thanks! I see that loop pushes up when I do that. How do I actually get the window open though. Pushing up more does not seem to slide it open, nor does pushing to the right.

Comment: Can you take a better picture of the end of the pole? I've seen windows that have an insertable (or removable, depending on your point of view) handle into a splined fitting. This might be similar, in which case you'd need to find the receiver and rotate the pole.

Comment: Does the bottom end of the pole have any features on it or is it smooth? I have seen windows like this that crank open.

Comment: here's what the pole looks like (both top and bottom pics are in there): http://imgur.com/a/81bvq

Comment: Looks like you push to go one way and pull the other way. No fitting for crank on the other end. Is there only one loop on the window frame or are there two? Presumably the window which opens is the one with a screen.

Comment: The purpose of the mushroomed end may be to hang it in the loop for storage.  (You don't really want to have this long pole resting unsecured where a dog or a child could pull it over and cause injury or damage.) For storage you'd insert the mushroomed end in the loop at an angle and then as it swung down to vertical it would be locked in place. This end may also serve double duty to open or close. The smaller end may engage a mechanism in a hole to either open or close the window.

Comment: The hole may have a spring loaded cover that the end of the pole pushes in to engage. This hole may be on the bottom of the window frame or the casing, and is pushed laterally to open or to close the window. Or one may push up or pull down.

Comment: Looks like an apartment building.  Ask a neighbor how to do it since they presumably have the same windows.

Comment: Carl, yes, but it is so much fun to try to figure out how it might work!